# Convertion of numeros

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I just saw some of my work today, and i want to enter the user how many alphabet they want and continue converting. Can i have help? It would be fantastic. I tried anything. I'm just new in java programming that's why. Thanks :)

This is my whole programming

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Try2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int counter = 0;
        int it = 0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.println("Enter words to digits: ");
        String alpha = keyboard.nextLine();
        alpha = alpha.toLowerCase();
        String num = (" ");
        while (counter < alpha.length()) {
            switch (alpha.charAt(it)) {
                case 'A':
                case 'a':
                case 'B':
                case 'b':
                case 'c':
                case 'C':
                    num += "2";
                    counter++;
                    break;
                case 'D':
                case 'E':
                case 'F':
                case 'd':
                case 'e':
                case 'f':
                    num += "3";
                    counter++;
                    break;
                case 'G':
                case 'H':
                case 'I':
                case 'g':
                case 'h':
                case 'i':
                    num += "4";
                    counter++;
                    break;
                case 'J':
                case 'K':
                case 'L':
                case 'j':
                case 'k':
                case 'l':
                    num += "5";
                    counter++;
                    break;
                case 'M':
                case 'N':
                case 'O':
                case 'm':
                case 'n':
                case 'o':
                    num += "6";
                    counter++;
                    break;
                case 'P':
                case 'R':
                case 'S':
                case 'p':
                case 'r':
                case 's':
                    num += "7";
                    counter++;
                    break;
                case 'T':
                case 'U':
                case 'V':
                case 't':
                case 'u':
                case 'v':
                    num += "8";
                    counter++;
                    break;
                case 'W':
                case 'w':
                case 'X':
                case 'x':
                case 'Y':
                case 'y':
                case 'Z':
                case 'z':
                case ' ':
                    num += "9";
                    counter++;
                    break;
            }
            if ((counter % 4) == 3) {
                num += "-";
            }
            it++;
        }
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more descriptive what you want about ?

Comment: All of your characters are lowercase, you have twice as many case statements as you really need.  You can also use (alpha.charAt(it)-'a'/3)+2 and get rid of your entire switch.

Comment: @ergonaut I think you meant `(alpha.charAt(it)-'a')/3+2 ` but this won't work for all letters.
@J.high You forgot 'q' in your `switch`

Comment: @AfsinBuyuksarac well i just want the user enter how many they want. the output must not stop in out input. i should just loop but i think there's a big problem in my program

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the read line code with another `while` loop:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true) {
    System.out.println("Enter words to digits: ");
    String alpha = keyboard.nextLine();
    alpha = alpha.toLowerCase();

    String num = " ";
    int counter = 0;
    int it = 0;
    while (counter < alpha.length()) {
        ...
    }
    //new line (optional)
    num += "\n";
}
```

You can check if the user entered a flag to end input:

```
//You can choose any flag you want
if(alpha.equals("finish")) {
    break;
}
```

---

About your switch:

- You can remove all the upper case letters because you wrote: `alpha = alpha.toLowerCase();`
- You forgot 'q'
- If `alpha` don't match: `[a-zA-z ]` (contains only letters and spaces) an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown from `alpha.charAt(it)` because you don't increase `counter` and the loop don't exit in time.

To prevent the last problem you can remove `counter` and `it` and change the `while` loop to `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length(); i++) {
    if ((i % 4) == 3) {
        num += "-";
    }
    switch (alpha.charAt(i)) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the so much help, and thank you, you corrected my mistakes :)